# Restoring filesystem of an extended root partition

Tags: filesystems, partition-table

I have a Debian/Windows 10 dual boot with a shared partition in between and I tried to extend my Linux root partition because I was running out of space.
I made some space but splitting the SHARED partition then deleted and re-created the Linux one with a start sector before the former one: (Linux is the 55.40Go partition)

[image: Partitions]

Now the Linux partition filesystem is not recognized anymore (For my information, if I had extended it from the end sector or used `resize2fs`, would it have been right?), so I am looking for a way to say "hey this partition is actually an EXT4".   I guess all the relevant informations are now in the middle of the partition and not at the beginning, maybe I can move it to the right place?

If not, maybe I can reset it to the former start sector? (I expended it by 10,000 MiB)

In any case, I can reinstall everything, I backed up all my data but I am curious to know if I can fix it.

Comment: Deleting & recreating a partition gives it new UUIDs, so grub & fstab now need updates. May be easier to reinstall, if not familiar with using live installer to edit install's files & reinstalling grub with chroot or Boot-Repair. What tools did you use. Always use Windows tools for Windows (NTFS) and Linux tools for Linux, gparted, fdisk, gdisk etc. You would have had to move a partition left & expand right with your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just "mark" this partition add ext4-formatted, as that is simply not the case: the filesystem starts at a different place than the partition start, so nothing can "understand" it.

(I can also only hope windows doesn't touch the data on partitions you extend inn that direction. But I'm optimistic!)

You'd have to move all the blocks forward from their old position, and then resize the file system. Probably much harder than undoing the partition resize, copying all files off to your backup, then resizing the partition, making a new file system and copying all files back. (Seeing you need a live Linux system to copy all the file, you can also "losetup" a loopback block device with an offset instead of first undoing the partition changes)

Answer (score 0):

If you remember the exact sector where the partition used to start, you may create it with exact same starting sector. If you did nothing with the space, the file system will show up as by magic. It may even notify you it found a file system there and ask to wipe it; don't do it! I suggest you to do this step first to make sure your file system is intact, so revert to the "last working state". If you don't remember where the file system used to be exactly, there are scanning recovery tools which scan the device and find all traces of file systems existed on this device. Beware if you had filesystem images in files, for example, images of virtual machines, scanning tools might be confused. The general procedure is something like described [here](https://habr.com/ru/company/hetmansoftware/blog/553866/).

Yes, extending the *end* side of the file system is the correct way. Say, you had a space after the partition, so you just remove the old partition and create the larger partition with the same beginning sector and then extend the file system; you can even do this online (without shutting down or unmounting). Or use *growpart*, which essentially performs this sequence.

Marcus is right, if you want to shift the partition towards the beginning of the disk, you should shift data physically. However, I suggest you to not to implement it yourself, but use the existing software which can do it for you, *Gparted* is an example (also exists as the [live USB](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) exactly for this purpose), thought there are many other tools like this.